# title tag and description tag in asp site

Tags: asp.net

I'm working in asp site, and I need to modify title and description. I'm working on website already developed and I dont have so much experience to understand it so well. I have many fields in the database where I can retrieve the title and description tags, but I need to put these data in this block. I dont know how.

Can you tell me where can I to include my DB fields.., what means the fields within squares.. [BriefDescription].

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/ElectroDos.Master" CodeBehind="detail.aspx.vb" Inherits="ElectroDos.results" EnableEventValidation="false" %>
```

```
<asp:Literal ID="MetaDescription"
 runat="server" 
 Text='<META name="DESCRIPTION" content="[MfrName] [ModelNumber] - [BriefDescription] - Available for rent from ElectroDos.">'
EnableViewState="false" />
<asp:Literal ID="Title" 
runat="server" 
Text="<title> [MfrName] [ModelNumber] product detail and options available from ElectroDos. </title>" 
EnableViewState="false" />
<meta content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<script src="/js/details.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: SInce they are server controls you can just set the `Text` property from the code behind however you want.

Comment: I have used something like Title.Text = "testing", but the text "testing" appears in the body, without any tag, the title tag doesnt change

Comment: You have to put the title tag into that text also

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I'm very noob in asp, so, I just have access to this site using ftp. can I edit CodeBehind files ? or that is compiled.., because I can't found any .vb file. that's why I ask you. and I'm modifyng it in inline, within the view directly.

Comment: It depends on the settings. It can be compiled beforehand or on server. If you can't find any code files then it's probably precompiled. And please, call it ASP.NET, ASP was something very different and may confuse people.

Comment: If it is compiled (in a library `.dll` file), you'll never get contents from the database into the page. You will have to modify the source, recompile and upload.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it from server side code. Just put id & runat server in title & meta tag, then set your desired content on those.

Web Page Code:

```
<head runat="server">
     <title runat="server" id="pageTitle"></title>
     <meta runat="server" id="metaDesc" name="DESCRIPTION" content="" /></head>
```

Server Side Code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pageTitle.Text = "[MfrName] [ModelNumber] product detail and options available from ElectroDos.";
        metaDesc.Content = "[MfrName] [ModelNumber] - [BriefDescription] - Available for rent from ElectroDos.";
    }
```

HTML Output:

```
<head>
<title>[MfrName] [ModelNumber] product detail and options available from ElectroDos.</title>
<meta id="metaDesc" name="DESCRIPTION" content="[MfrName] [ModelNumber] - [BriefDescription] - Available for rent from ElectroDos." /></head>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create meta tags in code behind and add them to the page header programatically.

```
//create a meta tag
HtmlMeta myMeta = new HtmlMeta();
myMeta.Name = "DESCRIPTION";
myMeta.Content = "[MfrName] [ModelNumber] - [BriefDescription]";

//add the meta tag to the page
Page.Header.Controls.Add(myMeta);
```

Or if you do use a `Literal`, you need to escape the `"` in code behind.

```
MetaDescription.Text = "<meta name=\"DESCRIPTION\" content=\"[MfrName] [ModelNumber] - [BriefDescription]\" />"
```